# How can I fix the scroll bug when using Windows rich edit controls in wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, textctrl

When using wx.TextCtl with the wx.TE_RICH2 option in windows, I get this strange bug with the auto-scroll when using the AppendText function. It scrolls so that all the text is above the visible area, which isn't very useful behaviour.

I tried just adding a call to ScrollLines(-1) after appending the text - which does scroll it to the correct position - but this can lead to the window flashing when it auto-scrolls. So I'm looking for another way to automatically scroll to the bottom.

So far, my solution is to bypass the AppendText functions auto-scroll and implement my own, like this:

```
def append_text(textctrl, text):
    before_number_of_lines = textctrl.GetNumberOfLines()

    textctrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()
    textctrl.WriteText(text)

    after_number_of_lines = textctrl.GetNumberOfLines()
    textctrl.ScrollLines(before_number_of_lines - after_number_of_lines + 1)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

```
    textctrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()
    textctrl.WriteText(licence)
    textctrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to fix the scroll bug when using Windows rich edit controls in wxpython:

```
textctrl.MoveEnd()
textctrl.WriteText(text)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.